# DataFormat.Error: We couldn't convert to Number

Tags: excel, powerquery

Using Power Query, I'm trying to change the type of a column that has values such as this into decimal.

[image]

But I get the following error:

> DataFormat.Error: We couldn't convert to Number.

This is when in my Advanced Options, the decimal separator seems to be `.` which is the one used in the column.

[image]

Comment: Can you give a particular entry in that column for which you get the error?

Comment: @JosWoolley I get the error for all of the values but here is the first one: `159.00000000`

Comment: also, check the source data if you do not have any non-numerical values in the column...
and how the number values are recorded (maybe they have gap/space in the end or the front?).
Powe query usually makes quite a good guess about the data type... In your case, it thinks it is a text...

Comment: @RolandasKol Yes, I am applying Trim and Clean to the column to no avail. This column used to contain the number followed by the currency e.g. `159.00000000 XRP`. I used the Split Column function to separate them because otherwise, I couldn't do any calculation. And now I am applying this change to decimal on the new column that only contains the numeric part of that value.

Comment: From the right dropdown menu when clicking the column, select change type **using locale** and select English-United States as the locale.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an index, then add a custom column with formula

```
=Number.From([Amount])
```

Filter that for errors and that will find you your problem data row

Comment: I think I solved the problem by replacing the `.` with `,`. It seems like `,` is how my system recognizes decimal numbers. But this is strange that is not what it's stored in my Excel options. So, I'm still confused.

Comment: most likely Regional Settings on Operating System has a major influence...